# How can show django auth-views URLs on swagger?

Tags: django, swagger

I set the Urls like belows.

**users>urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from users import views

....

path(
    "changePassword/", auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(), name="password_reset"
),  # 비밀번호 변경 (링크 발송)
path(
    "changePasswordDone/",
    auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(),
    name="password_reset_done",
),  # 비밀번호 변경(링크 선택 후 화면)
path(
    "changePasswordConfirm/<uidb64>/<token>/",
    auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(),
    name="password_reset_confirm",
),  # 비밀번호 변경(사용자 전송 링크)
path(
    "changePasswordComplete/",
    auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(),
    name="password_reset_complete",
),  # 비밀번호 변경(사용자 새 비밀번호 입력 후)
```

]

but the auth_views doesn't appear in the swagger like below images.

[image]

I guess there is some problem in the settings.py.... but don't know the detail.

**config>settings.py**

```
# Rest_Framework JWT
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES": (
        # 'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated', #401 에러 회피
        "rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny",  # 401 에러 회피
    ),
    "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": (
        "rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication",
        # 'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        # 'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
    ),
}
```

could you help kindly please?

Comment: Can you show users endpoint urls ? I think auth_views won't be shown as they are not api endpoints.